# How do I turn a messy build folder into an exe?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I used the setup.py build method to turn my .py into a .exe and it mad a build folder with the exe, 4 .dll files and another folder with loads of stuff in it, how do I turn all of this into one .exe?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `--onefile` parameter in the command? [Documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)